# Photoshop File Not Opening Directly After Saved

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My psd files are not opening. I can open a new file or open a jpeg image but cant open a file directly which has been saved in psd. Also, I can open them if I open photoshop and open a psd file from there but i can't open it directly.

The Photoshop icon doesn't appear on the saved file. A blank icon appears instead.

OS: Windows 7,
Photoshop Version: cs5

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the psd file in windows explorer, select "open with" - "choose default program"

From there you can tell windows to open that file type with Photoshop always (by clicking the box that says to always use this program)

note: if you don't see the "open with" option, hold the left shift button while you right-click on the file.

edit: what seems to have happened is somehow you've lost the association between .psd files and Photoshop. The above steps will recreate the association.